# Inserting bulk records. Perhaps with SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a button with a list of users in the table `ButtonUsers`. A parent `Button` is updated with the list of users, and all other Buttons' `UserList` should be updated. This isn't the case every time, therefore each button has it's own list.
The problem is that I have maybe 5000 buttons, that should each be updated.

I tried pulling all buttons at once, then pull the users necessary, and set each buttons state as modified. When I've iterated through all the buttons, call `SaveChanges()`.

```
public bool UpdatePreviousButtons(Button button, List<string> userList)
{
   var buttons = fieldRepo.GetFieldsCreatedFrom<Button>(button.ID);
   var users = fieldRepo.GetUsersFromIDs(userList);

   foreach(var btn in buttons)
   {
      btn.UserList = users;
      fieldRepo.UpdateFieldGeneric<Button>(btn);
   }

   return fieldRepo.Commit();
}
```

The problem seems to be that it doesn't bulk insert the records, instead it inserts one record per call. This inevitably leads to a time out, and takes far to long.

I have been thinking about doing it manually with `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`. Is there a better way, using Entity Framework?

Comment: It is common for ORMs (like EF) to work on a per-object basis; tools like `SqlBulkCopy` exist (and can be used with raw objects if needed), but they have fewer guarantees ("ACID" etc); you usually have to implement such things fairly manually. Alternatively, maybe consider "table valued parameters"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the SqlBulkCopy class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8

As a simple example of how it is used:

```
var data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("Name");
data.Columns.Add("Id");

for (var i = 1; i< 10_000; i++)
{
    data.Rows.Add($"Name={i+1}", i+1); 
}

using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionstring))
{
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "People";
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(data);
}
```

Comment: That looks like something that might work. Thanks for the example

Comment: Wow that worked really quick Thank you. As a bonus, is there something like this, to delete the current records, so that old data isn't left behind?

Comment: SqlBulkCopy just inserts as far as I know, this thread discusses ways to deal with requirements to update etc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889123/any-way-to-sqlbulkcopy-insert-or-update-if-exists